# What is cin>>str+1 in C++ string?

Tags: c++

```
char str[80];
cin >> str+1;
cout << str+1;
```

What does this +1 mean? How does it work? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks for reply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Comment: Someone wants to read to str[1] and onwards and doesn't care much for buffer overflow crashes!

Comment: @user657267 I can't see how this question is a duplicate of that one.

Comment: I think this is crap code. Bit unreadable imho

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's pointer arithmetic. `str` is an array of 80 `char`s. C++ supports an implicit array-to-pointer conversion, which means that in most expressions, `str` is automatically converted to a `char *`. `+ 1` is then applied to that pointer, yielding the same address as `&str[1]`.

```
cin >> str+1;
```

This reads from standard input, storing the result in the buffer starting at `str[1]`<sup>(1)</sup>.

```
cout << str+1;
```

This writes to standard output starting from `str[1]` and onwards until the NUL terminator<sup>(2)</sup>.

In effect, the operations just ignore the first element of the array `str`.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Notice that there is no bounds checking. If the input is longer than 78 characters (80 - 1 for the first char - 1 for the NUL terminator), Undefined Behaviour (most likely a buffer overrun) will happen.

<sup>(2)</sup> If there is no NUL terminator in the array, Undefined Behaviour will occur again.

Comment: I know it's not directly related to question, but this code will likely crash or behave unexpectedly when str has no null terminator.

Comment: @cubuspl42 You mean if the input is more than 78 characters? Yes, then it will be a buffer overflow.

Comment: Either way, when input is too long while reading, or when str doesn't contain '\0' while writing. I think that it's worth noting.

Comment: @cubuspl42 It can only not contain NUL when writing if the input was too long on reading. In the OP's code, there's no code in between the read and the write. Anyway, I believe I've pretty much covered this by saying that it goes "until the NUL terminator." That should imply somthing will not be right if there is no such terminator.

Comment: Oh, if it's to be taken literally, yes. I was thinking that's a kind of MCVE.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Edited in, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

In expression `str + 1` character array `str` is converted to pointer to its first element. Thus `str + 1` is pointer to the second element of the array.

That it would be more clear consider a simple program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello";

    for ( size_t i = 0; *( s + i ) != '\0'; ++i )
    {
        std::cout << s + i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The program output will be

```
Hello
ello
llo
lo
o
```